# Sharing ethernet over wi-fi with Network Manager and dnsmasq

Tags: networking, wifi, networkmanager, dnsmasq, wifi-hotspot

I'm running archlinux with kde desktop. I want to share my enp2s0 connection via wi-fi. So I've installed dnsmasq. Here are some configs:

/etc/resolv.conf

```
# Generated by resolvconf
search telecom.by
nameserver 127.0.0.1
nameserver 213.184.225.37
nameserver 213.184.224.254
```

/etc/dnsmasq.conf

```
user=dnsmasq
group=dnsmasq
port=53
cache-size=1000
domain-needed
bogus-priv
interface=wlp8s0 
dhcp-range=192.168.1.1,192.168.1.150,12h
dhcp-host=70:5A:B6:FE:6D:AD,192.168.1.1
listen-address=192.168.1.1
#dhcp-authoritative
```

Then I've created new connections in Network Manager - Wireless (shared):
[image: NM-config]

Now I can connect to this connection from my android phone. I can access my local rails server (192.168.1.1:3000) from phone, can use unified remote and airdroid to communicate with my phone, but I can't access external sites neither by address not by ip.
What should I do to be able to browse external sites via that connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I was doing wrong.
To share internet over wi-fi from other connection you need to set wi-fi adapter into AP-mode. So I've used [create_ap script](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=162895) and all is good now